# Add custom classes or theme a custom form

Tags: forms, 8

I have a custom form generated in a module.

I want to style the individual inputs by adding classes to them.

Can I add them through the `buildform()`?

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  //Return array of form API elements
  $form['location'] = array(
    '#type' => 'textfield',
    '#placeholder' => 'Enter your suburb or postcode...',
  );
  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => $this->t('Go'),
  );
  return $form;
}
```

If yes, how would I do this? I can't seem to find a good reference for parameters that can be passed into the `$form` array.

Alternatively, is there a way to pass the elements to a theme template like can be done with custom blogs or controllers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add classes in `#attributes`:

```
$form['submit'] = array(
     '#type' => 'submit',
     '#value' => $this->t('Go'),
     '#attributes' => ['class' => ['button']],
);
```